# My Double DQN algorithm for 2048 game never learns

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, keras, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to make Double-DQN algorithm to learn play 2048 game. My implementation is available in GitHub if you want to check the code. (https://github.com/codetiger/MachineLearning-2048)

My code is not learning after a basic level. Its not able to achieve more than 256 tile. Some of my predictions are below.

1. I am using a random player to train the code. I guess RL algorithms learn this way. They try all possible moves and learn from failures. I wild guess is, since I am training it using random moves the code is learns very limited.
2. The maximum episodes I tried is 4000. How do I calculate the optimal number of episodes.
3. There is a problem with my code.

I am not able to identify the issue with my approach. Would like to get some view on this.

My Pseudocode is here.

```
    for e in range(EPISODES):
        gameEnv.Reset()
        state = gameEnv.GetFlatGrid()
        state = np.reshape(state, [1, state_size])
        reward = 0.0
        prevMaxNumber = 0

        while True:
            action = agent.get_action(state)
            (moveScore, isValid) = gameEnv.Move(action + 1)

            next_state = gameEnv.GetFlatGrid()
            next_state = np.reshape(next_state, [1, state_size])

            if isValid:
                # Reward for step score
                reward += moveScore

                # Reward for New Max Number
                if gameEnv.GetMaxNumber() > prevMaxNumber:
                    reward += 10.0
                    prevMaxNumber = gameEnv.GetMaxNumber()

                gameEnv.AddNewNumber()
            else:
                reward = -50.0

            done = gameEnv.CheckGameOver()
            if done:
                reward = -100.0

            agent.append_sample(state, action, reward, next_state, done)
            agent.train_model()
            state = next_state

            if done:
                agent.update_target_model()
```

Answer (score 2):

My two cents,

- RL algorithms don't learn randomly. I suggest you take a look at 'Sutton and Barto (Second Edition)' for a detailed description of the wide variety of algorithms. Having said that I don't think the git code that you linked does what you expect (Why do you have an ES module? Are you training the network using evolutionary algorithms?). You might want to start off with simpler and stable implementations like this https://yanpanlau.github.io/2016/07/10/FlappyBird-Keras.html.
- 2048 is probably a difficult game for a simple Q-network to learn because it requires long-term planning. It's much easier for DQN to learn to play control/instant action games like Pong or Breakout but doesn't do well on games that need some amount of planning (Pacman, for example).